# React Router redirect on error 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, graphql, react-router-v4

Good evening, the problem I have has to do with react router.

**Here is my App.js in which all my routes are being processed**

```js
const App = () => (

      <div className="App">
        <MediaQuery minWidth={700}>
  {(matches) => {

    if (matches) {
      return (<Router>
    <div>
      <Headroom>
      <Header />
      </Headroom>
      <main>
        <Route exact path='/' component={homepage} />
        <Route path='/home' component={homepage} />
        <Route path='/OurPubs' component={OurPubs} />
        <Route path='/OurEmail' component={OurEmail} />
        <Route path='/OurQuest' component={OurQuest} />
        <Route path='/StayRelevant' component={StayRelevant} />
        <Route path='/GetCurious' component={GetCurious} />
        <Route path='/TheGoods' component={TheGoods} />
        <Route path='/post/:slug' component={Post}>
<Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Route>

      </main>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

As I use GraphQL to fetch data and work with templates (where every Post represents a Route in a sense)

As  **`<Route path='/post/:slug' component={Post}>`** brings the user to the different Posts.

Now if on mobile, after cache deletion, the browser will show a ERROR 404 message. Which is correct, after all the url post/XXXX does not actually exist on the server.

```
Not Found <br /> The requested URL /post/XXXX was not found on this server.
```

The problem only occurs on refresh inside a post or on mobile after exit of the browser.

**The question** is how I can simply bring the user from an unknown route back to path="/" (home)?

Comment: **I Think the problem is essentially that on try to refresh, the browser sends a request to a url that doesnt exist and hence cant load anything. As I dont have access to change the server configs Im pretty much clueless**

Comment: **Maybe Hash Routing will solve the issue?**

Answer (score 1):

When the call from server to fetch a post with that `slug` resolves in `Post` component, you need to check if it was 404, if yes then you'll navigate the User to home page.

```
...
fetch('/post/abc-post').then((obj) => {
  // check if you have 404 error
  if (obj.statusCode === 404) {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
})
...
```

If you give me more info about `Post` component, or where that call is made I can give you confident solution but the basic idea would be like above.

Comment: `query singlePost($slug: String!) {
  Post: Post(slug: $slug) {
    id
    slug
    title
    textContent
    coverImageURL
    description
}}`

Comment: That is my graphql query in which the slug which serves purpose for the url is being fetched. afterwards I export that slug into as seen above App.js where it is being used as a route. Here the export: `export default graphql(singlePost, {
  options: ({ match }) => ({
    variables: {
      slug: match.params.slug
   }})})(Post)`

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:
Configure your HTTP server to redirect all requests to /index.html

---

The problem here seems to be that your **HTTP server** is returning 404. This means that when you access /index.html (where the React code is), the application is loaded, and as the user interacts with the app, the URL changes without page reload with react-router.

When you refresh, you are asking your HTTP server for a file that is not your React app. So you should configure your HTTP server to redirect all requests (like /post/XXXX) to /index.html.

This question may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/188373/apache-2-2-rewrite-force-all-requests-to-index-html

Comment: The Problem is that I'm using React and if I call the index.html as seen in the "serverfault" Post, the site breaks and error is: `a2.blackoperatives.com/:1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://a2.blackoperatives.com/index.html".
index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: It turned out my server host has changed security rules which dont allow for the creation or alteration of .htaccess files.

Comment: what is your server host? they should provide support for creating some kind of `"when any url that is not .js,.css,.png, etc arrives, serve the index.html file"` rule. Note that you should not redirect. You want the url to be /XXX, but the webserver answers with the index.html
I would do it on the apache configuration using the FallbackReserouce:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: TL;DR: Your server host MUST help you with this configuration

Answer (score 0):

the one of fast way, you can set an Interceptor in your api client like fetch api,superagent and etc  like this :

```js
 if (!!response && response.status === 404) {
        store.dispatch(push("/404"));
    }
```

Comment: Would that be Apollo? I use Apollo on client side with graphql and graphcms (service as graphql Database)

Comment: try {
      const { data } = await graphql.query({ yourQuery });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response.status);
    }

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: everywhere you send your request client based on apollo documents [https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client]

Comment: mhhh error message is that await is a reserved word... Also should I place that in the return body of my Post.js file, in which the Post is being loaded, because you wrapped it in curly brackets?

Comment: `./src/pages/Post.js
Syntax error: await is a reserved word (16:10)

  14 | if (!loading) {
  15 |   return(
> 16 | { data  = await graphql.query({ singlePost }); } catch (err) { console.log(err.response.status); }
     ` Thats the error message when I put it in the return function...